# Any way to dynamically merge 2 different ranges?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I've been banging my head on the keyboard trying to get this done, and I can't seem to see a solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF5Xt.png)

Simply put, I want to get a the day in first column repeated for each item in column 3.
I've been trying to merge arrays with no luck.
I tried transposing them and merging by splitting, no luck.

If anyone can help me, I will think of you when I sleep.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sOaTVJ0j6tiKXD_0Cu-xAjywjrqv0Hzc0meiHJVezq8/edit#gid=1580905517

I tried adding {A2:A,C2:C4} and using array formulas for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `=arrayformula(split(flatten(A2:A6&"|"&transpose(B2:B4)),"|"))` and change the number format of column D back to the original YYYY-MM-DD format using Format/Number/Custom date and time.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
={tocol(map(tocol(A:A,1),lambda(z,wraprows(z,counta(C:C),z)))),
  tocol(map(tocol(C:C,1),lambda(z,wraprows(z,counta(A:A),z))),,1)}
```

[image]